# How do you write what you want to happen while game_state is "game" in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I asked you how to make a main menu window and a game window, buttons, and more. Okay, done. This is the code so far:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

pygame.display.set_caption("Baloon War!")
icon = pygame.image.load("Baloon war icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

def redrawMenuWindow():
    win.fill((0, 255, 110))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))

greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 255, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button ((255, 0, 0), 280, 380, 250, 100, "Quit")

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:
    if game_state == "menu":
        redrawMenuWindow()
    elif game_state == "game":
        redrawGameWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
                game_state = "game"
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

So then I wanted to make my main game part. After pressing the Start/greenButton the `game_state` is "game". But how do I write what the game should be like, where???? I didn't know how so I wrote this:

```
game_state = "game"
while game_state is "game":

    redrawGameWindow():
```

But this just doesn't work. Anyone here that can explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the game implementation in `redrawGameWindow`. You don't need any extra loop.

You have to draw the scene dependent on the state of the game `redrawMenuWindowin` `redrawGameWindow`. Note you can have more than 2 game states, then you'll need more functions, which draw the scene dependent on the state.

```py
def redrawMenuWindow():
    win.fill((0, 255, 110))

    # draw menu
    # [...]

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 180, 210))

    # draw main game part
    # [...]

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:

    if game_state == "menu":
        redrawMenuWindow()
    elif game_state == "game":
        redrawGameWindow()
    # elif game_state == "gameover":
    #    redrawGameoverWindow()  

    pygame.display.update()

    # [...]
```

And you have to handle the event dependent on the state of the game:

```
while run:

    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if game_state == "menu":

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                    print("clicked the button")
                    game_state = "game"
                if redButton.isOver(pos):
                    print("clicked the 2button")
                    run = False
            # [...]


        elif game_state == "game":

           # handel main game events
           # [...]
```